# How to get entries from a SQL table for past 22 weekdays/ 8 Weekends

Tags: sql

I want to get entries from the table for the past 22 weekdays or 8 weekends
I have one created_on column which serves as source of information for finding when the entry was created

I use it to extract dow and filter output by weekday and weekend

But I'm not able to figure out how can I get data for exactly 22 weekdays?

An example query would really help

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: can you show me what are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for DAYOFWEEK() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BETWEEN**.

*Example,*

```
WHERE tablename.created_on BETWEEN "01.06.2022" AND "15.06.2022"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `'DY'` date mask to filter the days and `CONNECT BY LEVEL` to get the date counts

```
  SELECT t.something, t.created_on
    FROM your_table t
   WHERE 22 = (SELECT COUNT(1)
                 FROM DUAL
                WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t.created_on ,'DD') + LEVEL - 1, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= SYSDATE - TRUNC(t.created_on,'DD') + 1);
```